# Vuejs conditional object set in computed property based on value in route params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

This seems so simple, but I can't get passed it. I have two arrays of objects in my store and the component finds the object for the template within one or the other based on a value in the route params. The value is a boolean and I am able to console log `this.$route.params.exampleValue` and get the result I expect (true or false). If it is false, I can't even console log inside the if statement:

```
computed: {
    example () {
      console.log(this.$route.params.isRelative) // either true or false
      if (this.$route.params.isRelative) {
        return this.$store.getters['ex1ById'](this.id)
      }
      return this.$store.getters['ex2ById'](this.id)
    }
}
```

I've tried it like above. I tried two sepearte ifs. I've tried starting with the negative (both `!this.$route.params.isRelative` and `this.$route.params.isRelative === false`). The route is set up to always have an `isRelative` boolean in it. The arrays are both full of objects in the store, getters look right and no typos there. Part of the issue might be that I am just conditionally rendering the list based on a check `v-if="Object.keys(example).length"`, but even when I remove that it's still not getting the object I am looking for with those ids.

Comment: What does your store look like?

Comment: Looks good. I have state set from the previous component or initial data fetch and these getters are able to find the correct object in state with that id passing through. If I simplify to one or the other, it works. I'm just not able to conditionally render based on that boolean, which is necessary.

Comment: Regardless though, I'm aiming to set up the component so it will always get an id and an isRelative boolean. I just changed the id and isRelative to required props, so they are 100% getting there and you could never navigate to this component without them. The id is for the getters and the isRelative bool is just to choose between the two getters. If I manually call either getter with a correct id for the array of objects in store, I get the object I expect back. So really the issue boils down to the computed property.

Comment: Should this.id be an array index?

Comment: Nevermind. Just realized the issue was that I was setting `isRelative` props through the routes, which coverts boolean to string. Doh! Thanks for talking it through anyway!

Comment: Haha glad things worked out for you in the end :)